# Can I use memcpy to write to multiple adjacent Standard Layout sub-objects?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, memcpy

**Disclaimer:** This is trying to drill down on a larger problem, so please don't get hung up with whether the example makes any sense in practice.

And, yes, if you want to *copy* objects, please use / provide the copy-constructor. (But note how even the example does not copy a whole object; it tries to blit some memory over a few adjacent(Q.2) integers.)

---

Given a C++ [Standard Layout](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/StandardLayoutType) `struct`, can I use `memcpy` to write to multiple (adjacent) sub-objects at once?

Complete example: ( <strike>https://ideone.com/1lP2Gd</strike> https://ideone.com/YXspBk)

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <memory.h>

struct MyStandardLayout {
    char mem_a;
    int16_t num_1;
    int32_t num_2;
    int64_t num_3;
    char mem_z;

    MyStandardLayout()
    : mem_a('a')
    , num_1(1 + (1 << 14))
    , num_2(1 + (1 << 30))
    , num_3(1LL + (1LL << 62))
    , mem_z('z')
    { }

    void print() const {
        std::cout << 
            "MySL Obj: " <<
            mem_a << " / " <<
            num_1 << " / " <<
            num_2 << " / " <<
            num_3 << " / " <<
            mem_z << "\n";
    }
};

void ZeroInts(MyStandardLayout* pObj) {
    const size_t first = offsetof(MyStandardLayout, num_1);
    const size_t third = offsetof(MyStandardLayout, num_3);
    std::cout << "ofs(1st) =  " << first << "\n";
    std::cout << "ofs(3rd) =  " << third << "\n";
    assert(third > first);
    const size_t delta = third - first;
    std::cout << "delta =  " << delta << "\n";
    const size_t sizeAll = delta + sizeof(MyStandardLayout::num_3);
    std::cout << "sizeAll =  " << sizeAll << "\n";

    std::vector<char> buf( sizeAll, 0 );
    memcpy(&pObj->num_1, &buf[0], sizeAll);
}

int main()
{
    MyStandardLayout obj;
    obj.print();
    ZeroInts(&obj);
    obj.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Given the wording in the [C++ Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf):

> ### 9.2 Class Members
>
> ...
>
> **13** Nonstatic data members of a (non-union) class with the same access control (Clause 11) are allocated so that later members have
>   higher addresses within a class object. (...) Implementation alignment requirements might cause two
>   adjacent members not to be allocated immediately after each other; (...)

I would conclude that it is guaranteed that `num_1` to `num_3` have increasing addresses and are adjacent modulo padding.

For the above example to be fully defined, I see these requirements, of which I am not sure they hold:

- `memcpy` must be allowed to write to multiple "memory objects" in this way at once, i.e. specifically

  - Calling `memcpy` with the target address of `num_1` and a size that is larger than the size of the `num_1` "object" is legal. (Given that `num_1` is not part of an array.) ([Is memcpy(&a + 1, &b + 1, 0) defined in C11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25390577/is-memcpya-1-b-1-0-defined-in-c11) seems a good related question, but doesn't quite fit.)
  - The [C++ (14) Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf), AFAICT, refers description of `memcpy` to the [C99 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), and that one states:

  > 7.21.2.1 The memcpy function
  >
  > **2** The memcpy function copies n characters from the object pointed to by s2 
  >   into *the object pointed to by s1*.

  So for me the question here wrt. this is whether the target range we have here can be considered "an object" according to the C or C++ Standard. Note: A (part of an) array of chars, declared and defined as such, *certainly* can be assumed to count as "an object" for the purposes of `memcpy` because I'm pretty sure I'm allowed to copy from one part of a char array to another part of (another) char array.

  So *then* the question would be if it is legal to reinterpret the memory range of the three members as a "conceptual"(?) char array.
- Calculating `sizeAll` is legal, that is usage of [`offsetof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof) is legal as shown.
- Writing to the padding in between the members is legal.

Do these properties hold? Have I missed anything else?

Comment: Don't use `memcpy()` or `std::copy()` for such situations. Provide copy constructors instead.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - You know, I *did* include a disclaimer, *and* the question contains the [lang-lawyer] tag. This is a site for SW professionals. I don't need to include the "don't do this at home, kids" sign, or do I?? :-P

Comment: The calculation of `delta` is undefined, as the pointers do not point into the same array. (Section 5.7, paragraph 6, last sentence.)

Comment: @MartinBa _"Do these properties hold?"_ It never was appropriate with any standard, and that didn't change. Your tagging doesn't help.

Comment: @MartinBa I already referred to the C++11 standard.

Comment: @MartinBa: What you wrote before was not "controversial"; it was not allowed by the standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting this as a partial answer wrt. `memcpy(&num_1, buf, sizeAll)`:

Note: [James' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39028624/321013) is much more concise and definitive.

I asked:

> - `memcpy` must be allowed to write to multiple "memory objects" in this way at once, i.e. specifically
>
>   - Calling `memcpy` with the target address of `num_1` and a size that is larger than the size of the `num_1` "object" is legal.
>   - The [C++ (14) Standard][2], AFAICT, refers description of `memcpy` to the [C99 Standard][3], and that one states:
>
>   > 7.21.2.1 The memcpy function
>   >
>   > **2** The memcpy function copies n characters from the object pointed to by s2 
>   >     into *the object pointed to by s1*.
>
>   So for me the question here wrt. this is whether the target range we have here can be considered "an object" according to the C or C++
>     Standard.

Thinking and searching a bit more, I found in the C Standard:

> § 6.2.6 Representations of types
>
> § 6.2.6.1 General
>
> **2** Except for bit-fields, objects are composed of contiguous sequences of one or more bytes, the number, order, and encoding of
>   which are either explicitly specified or implementation-defined.

So at least it is implied that "an object" => "contiguous sequence of bytes".

I'm not so bold to claim that the inverse -- "contiguous sequence of bytes" => "an object" -- holds, but at least "an object" doesn't seem to be defined more strictly here.

Then, as quoted in Q, §9.2/13 of the C++ Standard (and § 1.8/5) seem to guarantee that we *do* have a contiguous sequence of bytes (including padding).

*Then*, §3.9/3 says:

> **3** For any trivially copyable type T, if two pointers to T point to
>   distinct T objects obj1 and obj2, where neither obj1 nor obj2 is a
>   base-class subobject, if the underlying bytes (1.7) making up obj1 are
>   copied into obj2, obj2 shall subsequently hold the same value as obj1.
>   [ Example:
>
> ```
> T* t1p;
> T* t2p;       
>      // provided that t2p points to an initialized object ...         
> std::memcpy(t1p, t2p, sizeof(T));  
>      // at this point, every subobject of trivially copyable type in *t1p contains        
>      // the same value as the corresponding subobject in *t2p
> ```
>
> —end example ]

So this explicitly allows the application of `memcpy` to *whole* objects of *Trivially Copyable* types.

In the example, the three members comprise a "trivially copyable sub-object", and indeed I think wrapping them in an actual subobject of distinct type would still mandate exactly the same memory layout for the explicit object as for the three members:

```
struct MyStandardLayout_Flat {
    char mem_a;
    int16_t num_1;
    int32_t num_2;
    int64_t num_3;
    char mem_z;
};

struct MyStandardLayout_Sub {
    int16_t num_1;
    int32_t num_2;
    int64_t num_3;
};

struct MyStandardLayout_Composite {
    char mem_a;
    // Note that the padding here is different from the padding in MyStandardLayout_Flat, but that doesn't change how num_* are layed out.
    MyStandardLayout_Sub nums;
    char mem_z;
};
```

The memory layout of `nums` in `_Composite` and the three members of `_Flat` should be layed out completely the same, because the same basic rules apply.

So **in conclusion**, given that the "sub object" num_1 to num_3 will be represented by an equivalent contiguous sequence of bytes as a full Trivially Copyable sub-object, I:

- have a *very, very* hard time imagining an implementation or optimizer that breaks this
- Would say it either can be:

  - read as **Undefined** Behavior, **iff** we conclude that C++§3.9/3 implies that *only* (full) objects of Trivially Copyable Type are allowed to be be treated thusly by `memcpy` or conclude from C99§6.2.6.1/2 and the general spec of `memcpy` 7.21.2.1 that the contiguous sequence of the num_* bytes does not comprise a "valid object" for the purposes of memcopy.
  - read as **Defined** Behavior, **iff** we conclude that C++§3.9/3 does not normatively limit the applicability of `memcpy` to other types or memory ranges and conclude that the definition of `memcpy` (and the "object term") in the C99 Standard allows to treat adjacent variables as a single object contiguous bytes target.

Answer (score 2):

§8.5

> (6.2) — if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type, each non-static data member and each base-class
>   subobject is zero-initialized and padding is initialized to zero bits;

Now the standard does not actually say that these zero-bits will be writeable, but I can't think of an architecture that has this level of granularity on memory access permissions (nor would we want one to).

So I would say that *in practice* this re-writing zeros will always be safe, even if not specifically declared so by the Powers that Be.

Comment: Nice catch! I'm quite surprised the Standard explicitly defines the value of the padding. Grepping the PDF doesn't yield any further insight on the reason for me though.

Comment: "*Now the standard does not actually say that these zero-bits will be writeable*" Sure it does. It's an inevitable outgrowth of being able to `memcpy` between trivially copyable types.

Comment: @NicolBolas ah yes, you're right of course. This now begs the question of whether it is "defined behaviour" if any of these padding bits are given a non-zero value (for example as a result of memcpy).

Comment: @RichardHodges: `memcpy` is hardly the only way to give non-zero values to such bytes. Default initialization from raw memory allocations can do it too. Not unless you think that doing `new C` will blank out *just* the padding. Nothing in the standard *requires* that padding bytes have any particular value.

Comment: @NicolBolas - I would agree in practice of course, but I'm not sure from a Std POV: The requirements of `memcpy` wrt. TC types do not imply anything about the padding, so either before or after, the padding value is not defined by `§3.9 : 2, 3`. It talks about "original value" and "same value" - I'm not sure that padding can be considered part of the value. (Again, theoretically speaking.)

Answer (score 2):

> is legal to reinterpret the memory range of the three members as a "conceptual"(?) char array

No, arbitrary subsets of members of objects are not themselves an object of any kind.  If you can't take the `sizeof` something, it's not a thing.  Similarly, as suggested by the link you provided, if you can't identify the thing to `std::is_standard_layout`, it's not a thing.

Analogous would be

```
size_t n = (char*)&num_3 - (char*)&num_1;
```

It would compile, but it's UB: subtracted pointers must belong to the same object.

That said, I think you're in safe territory even if the standard isn't explicit.  If `MyStandardLayout` is a standard layout, it stands to reason that a subset of it also is, even if it has no name and is not an identifiable type of its own.

But I wouldn't do it.  Assignment is absolutely safe, and potentially faster than memcpy.  If the subset is meaningful and has many members, I would consider making it an explicit struct, and using assignment instead of `memcpy`, taking advantage of the default member-wise copy constructor supplied by the compiler.

Comment: Thanks. Good take on that. See my too-long answer on my considerations wrt. this issue.

Comment: "is a standard layout, it stands to reason that a subset of it also is" - I would say it is actually *mandated* by the rules for SL in the standard that "informal" composite sub-objects of a Standard Layout Type are identical with explicit composite sub-objects. (§9.2/13) Whether anything follows from this is another question though :-)