# How to change a compiler behaviour when getting a struct member via invalid pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct, gnu, ansi-c

I know about a feature, when we can get an offset of struct member via NULL or invalid pointer, like here:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
typedef struct  A {
        int c;
        int b;
} A;
int main() {
        A *a = (A*)0x100;
        fprintf(stderr, "%p\n", &((*a).b));
        fprintf(stderr, "%p\n", &a->b);
}
```

This program produces:

```
0x104
0x104
```

Is there a way to disable this feature and get a segfault or error instead?

Comment: Just deference the pointer to give you the segfault. All you are doing is printing pointer values. It is not a "feature" that you can "disable".

Comment: @Weather Vane , I dereference the pointers, for example here "&a->b" - 1)dereference a, 2)get b, 3)get address of b.

Comment: No, that is just an address, not its data. You do not try to get the *value of* `b`. Which is why you did not get a segfault.

Comment: If you want to get the offset of a `struct` member, use the standard `offsetof` macro. Don't use very questionable hacks, they can (and increasingly will) result in unexpected behaviour of your code with modern compilers and in modern C.

Comment: How do you expect to change compiler behaviour? By passing flags to it? You need to study *your* compiler and its flags then.

Answer (score 1):

You example is [arguably](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26906621/does-struct-name-null-b-cause-undefined-behaviour-in-c11) undefined behavior.

As such you can't expect to get a segmentation fault, which is a feature of the hardware anyway.

There is no way of guaranteeing that your example, or just a plain dereference of a null pointer will trigger the fault.