# C++ Getting parrent class with pointer arithmetic

Tags: c++

In the following code:

```
using Previous = std::atomic<void*>;
template<class T>
struct Element{
    Previous previous;
    T value;
}
```

Am I allowed to do pointer arithmetic to get `Element<T>*` from `T*` ?
Like this:

```
template<class T>
Element<T>* getElement(T* value){
   return static_cast<Element<T>*>(static_cast<void*>(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(value) - sizeof(Previous)));
}
```

Where `T` may be non-standard layout.

P.S. I clearly see that I cannot use [offsetof](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof) for this. But, may be for this special case, pointer arithmetic will work?

Comment: **NO**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member

Comment: I recommend less hacking and more fixing the design.

Comment: You're only allowed to do pointer arithmetic if the result is a pointer to an element belonging to the same array or one-past-the-end of that array. (`&x` behaves like a one-element array.) Everything else is undefined.

Comment: What I really want is an `template <typename Object, typename Member> Object* operator-(Member* member, Member Object::* ptr)` so you can subtract a pointer-to-member from a pointer to a member to get the pointer to the containing object.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: It depends on the compiler!

If you have a 64-bit compiler and `sizeof(Previous)` is 4 and `T` is a pointer data type the compiler (at least most compilers) will add 4 additional bytes between `previous` and `value`.

The pointer you get using:

```
(void *)(((unsigned char *)value) - sizeof(Previous)
```

... would point to the first byte after `previous` in this case!

However you might replace `sizeof(Previous)` by the following expression:

```
(int)&(((Element *)NULL)->value)
```

(Sorry that the expression above is a C expression; my C++ is not the best.)

This expression should always be constant: The address offset of the element in the parent structure.

---

**Edit**

Theoretically there could be compilers that do a `NULL` pointer check which will result in an error when using the expression above.

In this case the following expression will do the job:

```
((int)&(x.value) - (int)&x)
```

... while `x` is **any** object (e.g. a local variable) of the data type `Element`.

Comment: `(int)&(((Element *)NULL)->value)` - this will return offset between parent and value, right?

Comment: @tower123: Yes, it should. At least in C it does. I don't know about all C++ variants; C++.NET for example will not allow you to do pointer arithmetic at all...

Comment: You’d need to check the alignment of `T` to know how much padding was being introduced; you can’t assume it’s 4.

Comment: @DanielH I modified my answer.

Comment: The second sentence still says it’ll add 4 bytes, which just isn’t true if `T` is `char`, `char[12]`, `uint32_t`, or any other type with 4-byte alignment or less.

Comment: @DanielH Thanks. I modified the answer again.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26906621/does-struct-name-null-b-cause-undefined-behaviour-in-c11 dereference of a null pointer cause UB.

Comment: @tower120 This is true. Theoretically there could be compilers that do a NULL pointer check. However I doubt that there are such compilers - at least not compilers that allow pointer arithmethic.

Comment: @MartinRosenau  `((int)&(x.value) - (int)&x)` is it guaranteed to have the same offset across different object instances of the same type?

Comment: @tower120 Theoretically there could be C++ compilers which use different offsets. However I doubt there are such compilers.