# Is it undefined behaviour to use pointer after allocated memory?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

I have the following code:

```c
uint8_t buffer[16];
uint8_t data[16];
uint8_t buffer_length = 16;
uint8_t data_length = 0;

memcpy(buffer + buffer_length, data, data_length);
```

`memcpy` should be a no-op, because `data_length` is zero. However `buffer + buffer_length` points just outside of the allocated memory. I wonder if it could trigger some kind of undefined behaviour? Should I wrap this `memcpy` with an additional `if`?

I understand that any reasonable implementation of `memcpy` would work fine, however this question is more from the code correctness perspective and avoiding undefined behaviours.

Comment: You're allowed to create pointer to just after the end of an object. You're not allowed to dereference it. Since this doesn't dereference anything because the length is 0, I think it should be OK.

Comment: Using `buffer + buffer_length` doesn't violate the C standard, but is a loaded gun waiting to go off... Why would you want to form the address outside of the destination array in the first place?

Comment: In practice Barmar is correct.  And so is Rusty.  In theory, you would need to look at the precise wording of the specification of `memcpy` to decide if that call violates the spec's preconditions.

Comment: @Barmar In order to know if it's ok, we need to know what `memcpy` does in detail.

Comment: @klutt - You would need to know that for every possible implementation of `memcpy`.  Including those that haven't been written yet.  Or ... read the specification!!

Comment: @StephenC Just to be clear. I'm discussing this from a language lawyers perspective. And the specification does not say that nothing will be read from the `dst` argument

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243012/is-it-guaranteed-to-be-safe-to-perform-memcpy0-0-0?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 That question uses null pointers though, which are explicitly not valid pointers, per definition.

Comment: @Lundin Correct, i didn't say it is a duplicate, but i think it is related. Well, this one is probably closer related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29844298/is-it-legal-to-call-memcpy-with-zero-length-on-a-pointer-just-past-the-end-of-an?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @Fe2O3: speculating, but given there's no point even calling `memcpy` if you know the length is 0, I'm going to guess "because actually sometimes the length is non-zero, but in those cases the destination will end up being `buffer + buffer_length - data_length`". The questioner just needs to know if they have to put in `if (data_length)` to avoid UB by the standard. Nothing else makes sense to me.

Comment: @SteveJessop One could speculate all day... If one needs to alter the code to have it make any sense, then it may not be a good question.

Comment: @Fe2O3: well, the question is whether a particular piece of code has UB. Strictly speaking it can't be answered, but that's because anything less than a full program does not admit of having defined or undefined behaviour, per the standard. It's not because we don't know for sure why the questioner is asking: it's not UB if they're using the off-the-end pointer for one reason, but defined if they're using it for a different reason ;-)

Comment: And I don't think I can speculate all day. Like I said, that's the only explanation I can think of. I could only speculate for about 30 seconds, then I was out of ideas!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As the answer of Stephen C points out, the C17 specification is a bit vague about whether or not this is well-defined.

However, the C23 specification clarifies this in a footnote to the part of 7.1.4 stating

> If a function argument is described as being an array, the pointer passed to the function shall
> have a value such that all address computations and accesses to objects (that would be valid if
> the pointer did point to the first element of such an array) are valid.

The footnote (235) reads:

> This includes, for example, passing a valid pointer that points one-past-the-end of an array along with a size of 0, or using any valid pointer with a size of 0.

The first part of the sentence explicitly defines the OP case as well-defined.

Adding this statement can be seen as admitting that the C17 specification is not sufficiently clear on this point and thus, it cannot be ruled out that an implementer of a C17 compiler may in good faith interpret the standard such that this case is not defined behavior.

However, C23 should remove that uncertainty.

Comment: Thats footnote 235) in the C23 N3096 draft. And either way, foot notes are not normative. Although this one ought to point a knowledgeable reader straight to the actual normative text in 6.5.6 (C17/C23), as quoted in my answer.

Comment: @Lundin That is correct, but in this case, I see the footnote as a clarification of how the normative paragraph should be interpreted. It is not adding to the specification.

Comment: Yeah it's a good find - I don't think the clarification was necessary prior to C23 but apparently some people need one. It's generally muddy thinking to say that something in chapter 7 (the standard library) invalidates the rules laid out in chapter 6 (the C language). The standard library need not be implemented in the C language, but the function APIs definitely need to be and therefore (for the most part) the same rules apply to standard library functions as to any C function.

Comment: @Lundin: Such clarification *shouldn't* have been necessary, but there are many situations where the authors of the Standard didn't think it necessary to explicitly specify various aspects of behavior which implementations to date had either processed identically or in one of a few discrete ways (possibly chosen in unspecified fashion), but which clever compiler writers have interpreted such omissions as invitations to deviate in arbitrary fashion.  The real problem, though, should be handled by recognizing adherence to precedent as a quality-of-implementation matter.

Comment: Surely the issue is *valid* pointer. If you can't unconditionally guarantee that, you may create a heisenbug. A buffer returned by a memory allocator  might be to the last bytes in a page and therefore a pointer one off the end, might be to a non-existent or non-accessible virtual address. This isn't impossible even with stack allocation, if the hardware is performing some sort of stack-smashing-protection.

Comment: @nigel222 It is not allowed for a C implementation to allocate memory such that a pointer one past the end is invalid. The standard specifies that pointer arithmetic with a "one-past-the-end" pointer must be well-defined. However, dereferencing such a pointer is UB.

Comment: @nigel222: If you allocate some whole number of aligned pages, and form `begin` and `end=begin+length` pointers, yes, `end` will point to the start of the next page.  It's legal to have a pointer variable holding this pointer value, but it would be UB to do `++end`.  (On machines with flat memory models, pointer math is just unsigned integer math, but it's still UB in C, and some compilers for flat-memory-model machines may choose not to define the behaviour in such cases even though they trivially can.)  As you say, it's UB to deref, but `memcpy(end,end, 0)` is required not to.

Comment: If assigning p + 1024 to another pointer is undefined behaviour, then malloc isn't allowed to allocate 1024 bytes starting at p. If dereferencing p + 1024 is undefined behaviour, then malloc may return p if you allocate 1024 items.

Comment: //...may in good faith...//  A compiler writer that isn't making a good faith effort to process programs usefully could write a compiler that is technically conforming and yet will still--in the words of the C99 Rationale--"succeed at being useless".  Compiler writers who seek to exploit such minutiae in the Standard to justify breaking what would otherwise be useful programs should be recognized as acting in bad faith, whether or not the Standard technically forbids such exploits.

Answer (score 9):

The code has well-defined behavior.

The "string handling functions" that the `memcpy` function sorts under states (C17 7.24.1):

> Where an argument declared as `size_t n` specifies the length of the array for a function, `n` can have the value zero on a call to that function. Unless explicitly stated otherwise in the description of a
> particular function in this subclause, pointer arguments on such a call shall still have valid values, as described in 7.1.4.

The part in C17 7.1.4 regarding array parameters passed to standard library functions is somewhat relevant:

> If a function argument is described as being an array, the pointer actually passed
> to the function shall have a value such that all address computations and accesses to objects (that
> would be valid if the pointer did point to the first element of such an array) are in fact valid.

(The arguments to `memcpy` need not necessarily be an array/arrays however. But in this case they both are.)

Address computations and the following access to an item of the array are defined by the rules for pointer arithmetic, specifically C17 6.5.6 §8 about the additive operators, the relevant part being this one:

> If both the pointer operand and the result point
> to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation
> shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior is undefined. If the result points one past
> the last element of the array object, it shall not be used as the operand of a unary * operator that is
> evaluated.

Therefore `buffer + buffer_length` is *explicitly* allowed by this "point one item past the end of an array" special rule, as long as we don't de-reference that location. Which will not happen in this case. Had we written `buffer + buffer_length + 1` then it would be an invalid address computation and undefined behavior.

Comment: But doesn't 7.24.1 explicitely state, that the pointers passed have to be valid? If for example a particular implementation probes the destination pointer and discovers (by means of a hardware trap) that it is an invalid location, where would this be disallowed in the standard? The fact that buffer+buffer_length is a well-defined operation does not mean, that passing it to a function is well-defined.

Comment: @Jens: I think you're conflating two things: a valid pointer, and a pointer that can be dereferenced. one-off-the-end of an array is a valid pointer for many purposes. The question then is whether this is one of them. Can `memcpy` legitimately probe the byte at address `dest`, which is *outside* the 0-length region of memory starting at `dest` that you've told `memcpy` to write to? The general thrust of the standard is "no, `memcpy` must not do that", and it's for the same reason it must not dereference `dest+1` when you passed in `dest` and length 1.

Comment: At least, not if it might trap. If an implementation wants to make special arrangements so that end-of-array always can be read for (at least) one byte, then its implementation of `memcpy` is welcome to do so under the "as if" rule.

Comment: For that matter, if the implementation wants to deference `dest+1024` on every call to `memcpy`, because it happens to know it's running on an architecture where it's safe to dereference literally any address: then that's permitted too. It conceivably on some non-stupid architecture even helps pre-populate cache lines to speed up big copies. But it's up to the implementation to make sure it's safe *for that C implementation*: it's not on you to pass it a pointer for which `dest+1024` can be dereferenced *per the standard*.

Comment: This is why it's always funny when authors of the Linux kernel have rows with authors of GCC over how the C standard should be interpreted. Often kernel code is running in contexts where either it wants some behaviour beyond the standard (such as the effect of dereferencing a null pointer, famously), and/or where the kernel code is *part of* the C implementation, not really C application code at all. Like, obviously the kernel memory allocator can't expect `malloc` to behave as specified, because it'll just recurse. But sometimes it's much less obvious. Such fun.

Comment: @SteveJessop - as one example of such behavior, I've seen memcpy implementations that will over-read the input buffer, staying within the same page mind you. Works fine under the as-if rule so long as the rest of the implementation keeps it in mind.

Comment: As a tangential example, GCC will in practice quite happily speculatively load a potentially-uninitialized `_Bool` from known-dereferenceable memory. This is not guaranteed to be valid by C spec - said `_Bool` could be a trap representation - but so long as GCC ensures it's safe in practice on that particular implementation it's fine.

Comment: @Jens Valid pointers in the context of the C standard are those pointing at a well-defined location. As opposed to null pointers and pointers with indeterminate values/trap representations. The pointer pointing one past the end of the array is not allowed to be a trap representation or it wouldn't conform to the quoted 6.5.6. De-referencing it would be undefined behavior, but memcpy with size zero is not allowed to de-referencing anything.

Comment: @TLW: Terminology nitpick: "trap representation" includes ABI-violations like a `_Bool` object whose byte has a value other than `0` or `1`.  Even if the target ISA won't take an exception from running instructions on it (like `-0` in some one's complement machines, IIRC), ISO C17 calls that a trap rep: *6.2.6.1/5 - Certain object representations need not represent a value of the object type. If the stored value of an object has such a representation and is read by an lvalue expression that does not have character type, the behavior is undefined ...*

Comment: @TLW: But yes, despite the name ISO C and C++ apply, it fine to speculatively load such a `_Bool` as long as no faults can happen on executions that avoid UB in the abstract machine.  (Related: *[Does the C++ standard allow for an uninitialized bool to crash a program?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54120862)* - if your source code *does* use the value of a trap-representation `bool`, your program is allowed to crash, and might do so in practice with real compilers.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Do you know of any ABI actually having trap representations for booleans though? I think it is far more common (and more relevant to this question) to have trap representations for pointers - there are many ISA which will keep track of data vs code and if you try to run code in data memory or vice versa, it will trap. So it might even trap at the point of conversion, for example when you do something like `(void*)function_pointer`. I vaguely recall various PowerPC doing things like that.

Comment: @Lundin: The x86-64 System V ABI specifies that a `_Bool` is a byte with value `0` or `1`.  In ISO C terminology, anything else is a trap representation, as discussed in my linked answer.  If you actually meant whether any **ISAs** have `_Bool` values that can trap in assembly language (not just because compiler code-gen assumed 0 or 1), not that I'm aware of, except I guess some old one's complement machines where negative-zero (bit-pattern `0xff...`) could trap when used with arithmetic instructions.  But perhaps you'd use unsigned math instructions on bools if doing something like b1 == b2.

Comment: @PeterCordes "In ISO C terminology, anything else is a trap representation" No - anything else _may_ be a trap representation. But it isn't actually one unless explicitly specified by the ABI/ISA. Whereas my object/function pointer example will generate a hardware exception on some known and existing ISA (pretty sure it was PowerPC). The distinction between "might be a trap" and "is a trap" is significant - you can safely use indeterminate values on systems where no corresponding trap representations exist. Unspecified behavior (garbage values) vs undefined behavior (crash & burn).

Comment: As shown in that Q&A I linked, an unitialized `bool` with a value other than 0 or 1 does in practice crash with clang's code-gen for x86-64 System V.  All values other than 0 or 1 are trap reps for `bool`, and thus *allowed* to crash, because the ABI says bool won't have such values.  And compilers are allowed to assume that.  I was hesitant to use the term "trap representation" to talk about things that only fault because of software assumptions, but look at the ISO C17 definition I quoted: *an object-representation that doesn't represent a value of that type*. That includes any ABI violation

Comment: Or to put it another way, if an ABI specifies that a type can only have certain values, any other object-representation is automatically a trap representation, unless the ABI goes out of its way to specify that they're allowed, and e.g. should be treated as indeterminate values, but not trap representations.  The x86-64 SysV ABI doesn't do that, so in ISO C terms those other bit-patterns "trap representations".  That makes it UB to do anything with them, giving compilers permission to assume 0 or 1 and make asm that can crash on other values. (That's how I'd categorize the observed behaviour.)

Comment: @PeterCordes It is well-known that clang misbehaves in case of indeterminate values and that has nothing to do with trap representations, but clang going completely ape**** when faced with indeterminate values https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75533693/clang-15-miscompiles-code-accessing-indeterminate-values. It just stops code generation halfways through the assembly and lies down to die. See the comments too which were migrated to chat and the linked bug reports. There's been a discussion within the ISO C WG with no clear consensus about what's been dubbed "wobbly values" in various DR.

Comment: @PeterCordes As for the compiler being able to assume that a bool only has value 1 or 0, that's true though, and it may optimize accordingly. Anyway, this is going wildly off-topic - the discussion here was regarding a a pointer pointing one item past the last item in an array.

Comment: The point you bring up for Clang 15 compiling C doesn't sound great to me, either.  But none of those things were the problem in the `_Bool` Q&A I linked: it was doing `memcpy(valid, valid, 5U - bool)` and wrapping to a huge unsigned size.  That would happen even if you'd used `memcpy` or a `char*` to set the object-representation of a `_Bool` to an ABI-violating value, aka a "trap representation".  It wasn't the compiler giving up due compile-time visibility of a read-uninitialized (even though that alone is fully UB in C++, unlike in ISO C's actual wording)  Agreed it's off topic here.

Comment: @Lundin: One of the reasons I dislike `bool` is that it creates trap representations at the language level even on platforms where all bit patterns would otherwise represent valid values for all types.  IMHO, it would have been more useful if the Standard had specified that every action that read a `bool` whose underlying storage is a non-zero even number will yield an independent Unspecified value or raise an Implementation-Defined asynchronous signal, and a read where the underlying storage is an odd number other than one will yield an independent Unspecified odd value or raise IDA signal.

Comment: @Lundin: With regard to your hypothetical non-stupid platform, I think it would be entirely reasonable for a compiler targeting such a platform where read dereferences are almost always safe to document that it will read-dereference `(char*)src+size` before testing `size` in certain compilation modes unless a certain compilation flag is used to suppress such behavior, if all implementation-created allocations would satisfy that requirement.  Programmers using such an implementation while linking with code processed by other implementations would need to ensure that this doesn't cause trouble.

Comment: @Lundin: Unfortunately, the Standard makes no distinction between situations where some rare implementations might have a good reason for handling a few corner cases in unusual fashion, from those where even programmers targeting commonplace implementations should be expected to go out of their way to accommodate such possibilities.

Answer (score -2):

If the question is whether an conforming implementation could process such pointer constructs in gratuitously wacky fashion, the answer is almost certainly yes.  If the question is whether programmers should be expected to jump through hoops to allow for such possibility, the answer is no.  The Standard treats many such judgments as quality of implementation issues outside its jurisdiction.

In both clang and gcc, an equality comparison between a pointer to the start of an object, and a a legitimately formed "one past" pointer for the object that happens to immediately precede it in memory, may have side effects which are consistent neither with the comparison yielding 0, nor with it yielding 1.  It would not, however, would probably not render such compilers non-conforming, because there would almost certainly exist some possible program which nominally exercises the translation limits in N1570 5.2.4.1, which clang and gcc would process correctly.

If there were an implementation that were incapable of correctly processing any program that exercises the translation limits in N5.2.4.1, other than one which passes a just-past pointer to `memcpy` with a size argument of zero, then one could argue that failure to treat that operation as a no-op might render the implementation non-conforming, or one could argue that because the Standard fails to unambiguously make clear that such behavior is required, the Standard would impose no requirements on a program that performs such an operation, but neither of those arguments would detract from the fact that quality implementations should be expected to treat the operation as a no-op, but the Standard would allow poor quality implementations to process such constructs in nonsensical fashion.  Since the Standard deliberately waives jurisdiction over such quality-of-implementation issues, it should not be used as a source of guidance on such matters.

Comment: At risk of spoiling your fun, is answering every such question with, "C is a failed standard and means nothing. It has become a reverberating gong or a clashing cymbal" actually putting any pressure on the standard-writers, or implementers, or even C programmers? Any movement towards a document defining what a "quality implementation" of C is? ;-)

Comment: That said, the comparison thing is rather significant for `memmove`, where you might reasonably expect the implementation to do some implementation-specific comparison of `src` and `dest` to decide how to copy. C++'s "potentially overlapping" concept provides implementations with a caveat along these lines, although I confess to having rather lost track of all this in recent years.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Simple principle: if the simplest way of accomplishing a task with -O0 is simpler than any way that could be guaranteed to work at higher optimization settings, then for purposes of that task the so-called "optimizations" aren't.  Otherwise, I think looking at compilers which aren't based on clang or gcc, and for which people are willing to pay money, should offer a clue.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Both gcc and clang operate on an assumption that if two pointers compare equal, and a compiler would be entitled to assume that one of them wouldn't be used to access a particular object, it may apply that same assumption to both, despite the fact that the Standard explicitly recognizes situations where pointers would not be usable to access the same object and yet compare equal.  Bug reports on such issues have been filed, but the compiler behavior is never changed.  How should I interpret the seeming contradiction between clang/gcc behavior and the Standard?

Comment: well, I haven't looked at those issues to form an opinion of my own, but I think it's fine to conclude that if clang/gcc do not behave as required by the standard, then neither is a conforming implementation. People do reach difference conclusions from the same text, so far as what is required by the standard. gcc in my experience doesn't make it easy enough even to disable individual optimisations that explicitly make it non-conforming, let alone disabling ones that the user thinks make it non-conforming but the author thinks conform.

Comment: So anyway, if gcc and clang `memcpy` don't conform, then as well as knowing whether this is UB, the questioner might also need to know whether it works in any non-conforming C-inspired environment(s) they use! But that follow-up would be a concrete question about the effect of passing a one-past-end pointer and a length of 0 into `memcpy`. I'm not convinced the standard *does* consider that a quality-of-implementation issue, I think it does require this to be OK. Other stuff about pointers that's bitten other people on other occasions, may be less clear.

Comment: I am entertained by your "worst case scenario" interpretation of the standard that the "implementation limits" clause is a blanket permission to implementations, that they conform provided there exists at least one program (with the required limits) for which they produce the correct observable behaviour. I just don't read the standard that way myself. Do gcc authors trying to weasel out of a bug report actually clam to interpret it that way?

Comment: I'll think about your principle, though. My first instinct is that it's not quite right. Actually there probably exist some simple-but-flagrantly-UB programs that "just so happen" to work at -O0 on some implementation, then get caught out at a higher level. The correct fix is to make the program more complex, but nevertheless *for that task* the optimisations are still optimisations, even though *for that cack-handed program* they aren't. I can't immediately construct such a cack-handed program to prove it, but I expect there are some on "code review" :-)

Comment: The problem of course being that compiler authors can (if they choose) start from the position that their implementation is perfect and *any* program broken by their optimisations is "cack-handed" in this sense. Then as you say, it's difficult to litigate the standard.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Have you read the published Rationale for the C Standard?  I think it's pretty clear that the authors intended UB to be recognized as a catch-all for many concepts, including constructs which most implementations were expected to process identically 100% of the time, but where it might be useful for *some* implementations to deviate from normal sequential program semantics on at least some not-entirely-predictable occasions.  On a platform where signed overflow would trap, making it Implementation Defined would forbid reordering arithmetic operations that might trap across...

Comment: ...other operations, even in cases where such reordering would not affect a program's ability to satisfy application requirements.  The only situations where anyone would have been expected to care about whether or not the Standard defined some corner case that all implementations handled identically would be those where there would be some advantage to having an implementation do something else.  And if nobody could imagine any particular situation where that would occur, it would be impossible for the Committee to weigh the pros and cons of deviating from the common behavior if it did.

Comment: @SteveJessop: I think the Standard could and should be written robustly if it adopted the principle that (1) any implementation may reject (via defined means) any program for any reason, but (2) every implementation must fully specify (possibly be reference) its requirements for compilation and target environments, and only indicate that it has successfully produced an executable artifact in cases where running that artifact on an environment satisfying requirements would yield conforming behavior (which might include indicating via defined means a refusal to continue processing).

Comment: @SteveJessop: If one drops the goal of requiring that all implementations accept all programs--a goal that would require either saying the language could only be implemented on platforms that could handle complicated tasks, or that conforming programs would be limited to simple tasks, but instead focuses on requiring that conforming implementatiosn *reject all programs they can't process in required fashion*, that will allow a variety of implementations to handle tasks for which they are tailored, far better than any "one size fits all" specification could.

Comment: @SteveJessop: BTW, I remember once upon a time, in the early 2000's, being in an on-line chat with a Committee member who despised C99.  I wish I could remember his name, but he feared that it would create a gulf between constructs that would work correctly 99.9% of the time and those which would be specified to work 100% of the time.  I thought at the time that he was being overly alarmist, but I wish I'd taken him seriously back then and shared his message when phony notions of "optimization" were beginning to take hold, but the community hadn't yet been gaslighted.

Comment: Well, I guess that's the crux. If gcc's optimizations make code run faster then they are precisely that case anticipated by the standard without knowing when it would happen, "useful for some implementations to deviate from normal sequential program semantics". If they don't make real code run faster then indeed they're "phony" and it's all just a competitive benchmarking game that severely harms users. Ultimately everyone knows what they *want* their compiler to do, and when that's not what it does they complain about Microsoft's phony longs or whatever.

Comment: It's basically the same deal as tax avoidance. One side bangs on about "the spirit and intent of the law", which they can't define. The other one is almost certainly in fact breaking the law, some of the time, because that's what happens when you run as close to the boundary as you can. But it's incredibly difficult to prove when.

Comment: @SteveJessop Many of gcc's transforms have the primary effect of turning programs that would take awhile to produce correct results into programs that quickly produce wrong results.  The authors of gcc pretend that if the programs were properly written they'd quickly produce right results, but in actuality any way of writing the program that could be guaranteed to produce correct result would block the optimizing transform, negating any performance advantages it was supposed to offer.

Comment: @SteveJessop: A key aspect of "the law" which proponents of phony "optimizations" ignore is that UB means nothing more nor less than that *the Standard waives jurisdiction*.  The real problem is that when the Standard was written primary authority lay with programmers deciding what compilers they wanted to use, and compiler writers who had to design compilers that programmers wanted in order to sell their products.  Programmers wanting to release open-source software, however, don't really have any choice except to make it compatible with open-source compilers, ...

Comment: ...whose authors in turn have no desire to encourage programmers to optimize their code for maximum performance on commercial compilers.  If programmers were to write programs that worked okay on gcc, but better on commercial compilers, many programmers would do so, making it worthwhile for many computer users to buy commercial compilers to get better performance from such programs.  Unfortunately, programmers' power in the compiler marketplace has been essentially nullified.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I meant if gcc's optimizations made "correct" code run faster, not just if they made "code" run faster. You claim is clear, that none of these finicky optimizations make real programs run faster without changing their results (i.e. the code was incorrect in the opinion of gcc's authors).

Comment: @SteveJessop: Note that gcc is designed to behave contrary to the Standard even in some cases where the Standard is extremely explicit.  For example, if `p` points to the start of a global scope`int y[1];` whose address coincides with the "just past" address of `int x[1];`, then `*p` may be used to access `y[0]` even if code has happened to also compare `p` for equality with `x+1` and observed that they were equal.  The Standard expressly provides for equality comparison in that scenario, but clang and gcc make no effort to handle it reliably.

Comment: OK, so for example you might do `if (x+1==p) *p = 1 else *p = 0`, with the intention that the value of `y[0]` tells you whether or not the objects are adjacent. And then both compilers will blow you up? How pathological is it: does it also blow up `y[0] = (x+1 == y)` since it knows at compile time the objects will be adjacent? Or perhaps reduce that to `y[0] = 0` on grounds that it incorrectly claims the code is not valid when the pointers are equal?

Comment: @SteveJessop: If one performs a read of `y[i]` and then after performing a conditional write to `p` one reads both `y[i]` and `y[j]`, with `i` and `j` both happening to hold zero, but not being statically identifiable as equivalent, the reads of `y[i]` may yield the old value and `y[j]` the new value--behavior which would be consistent neither with the comparison having reported the addresses equal, nor with its having reported them unequal.  Even in cases where it wouldn't matter which branch was chosen, having `y[i]` and `y[j]` yield different values when there is no rule that would...

Comment: ...allow for such a possibility makes reasoning about anything impossible.  There are many situations where clang and gcc treat constructs as equivalent, without adding proper annotations to the replacement forms.  Replacing a conditional write to `*p` with a combination of an actual write to `x+1` and an artificial memory clobber of `*p`, for example, would be a legitimate substitution, since the artificial memory clobber of `*p` would still prevent the illegitimate assumption that `y[i]` could not have been modified.

Comment: Oh I see, so basically it's illegitimately expanding the strict aliasing rules along the lines of, "a one-past-the-end pointer cannot alias a pointer to an object". Which is thoroughly pointless, since you never dereference one-past-end, so who cares what it does and doesn't alias. And also false. Then it wrongly thinks the fact `p` is equal to `x+1` means that it cannot be an alias of `y[0]`, and applies non-aliased-pointer optimizations?

Comment: @SteveJessop: Yup.  This treatment would be legitimate if the compiler always added padding between exported symbols, and specified that its output may only be linked with that of other compilers that do likewise, but clang and gcc do neither of those things.  Further, such discussions ignore the real problem: the notion that the only way to allow compiler optimizations is to classify as UB any scenario where useful compiler optimizations might observably affect program behavior, rather than explicitly acknowledging various kinds of allowable transforms and what must be done if the effects...

Comment: ...would prevent a program from *satisfying application requirements*.  In many cases, the most effective optimizations would visibly affect program behavior, *but in ways that would be irrelevant to application requirements*.  If a program receives invalid input, having `x*30/15;` yield `(int)((unsigned)x << 1)` vs `(int)(x*30u)/15` may both be equally acceptable, even if having code arbitrarily corrupt memory would not be.  Classifying overflow as UB would render the substitutions unusable in any code which needed to be robust against invalid input.

Comment: Out of interest, does gcc mess this up for adjacent subobjects, or only for adjacent external-linkage objects with different names?

Comment: @SteveJessop: So far as I can tell, neither gcc nor clang *presently* applies this kind of transformation for adjacent subobjects, but I wouldn't be surprised if they do so for some two-dimensional-array-related scenarios I haven't found yet.