# Most Efficient way to normalize 1MB text file?

Tags: c++, c

I have 1MB text file.
I want to remove spaces, new line, tab and convert case of character from Lower case to uppercase of 1MB file by 4KB iteratively.

I have Write this code:

```
for (i = 0, j= 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        switch (Buffer[i])
        {
            case 'a':
            case 'b':
            case 'c':
            case 'd':
            case 'e':
            case 'f':
            case 'g':
            case 'h':
            case 'i':
            case 'j':
            case 'k':
            case 'l':
            case 'm':
            case 'n':
            case 'o':
            case 'p':
            case 'q':
            case 'r':
            case 's':
            case 't':
            case 'u':
            case 'v':
            case 'w':
            case 'x':
            case 'y':
            case 'z':
                    NormalisedBuffer[j] = Buffer[i] - 32;
                    ++j;
                break;

            case ' ':
            case '\t':
            case '\r':
            case '\n':
                break;

            default:
                NormalisedBuffer[j] = Buffer[i];
                ++j;
        }
    }
```

Is there any way to do this in less-time and efficient way?

Comment: You could use functions like `islower()` and `toupper()`. The implementors have probably coded these in the most efficient way (they're probably implemented as macros).

Comment: Do you *have* to do it in C? If you're on a POSIX platform (like Linux or OSX) then there are shell commands that can do it for you.

Comment: If nothing else, it will make your code easier to read and less error prone (you could easily leave out a letter in that `case` statement and no one would notice).

Comment: Otherwise I recommend [this reference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte).

Comment: (*If* there is a bottleneck - run a performance profile, no point chasing purple dragons - I would suspect it is related to the I/O portions.)

Comment: Have you actually measured the time it takes? I expect converting 1MB to upper or lower and stripping out whitespaces would take so little time that it's barely measurable...

Comment: It take 12 seconds for 100 files.

Comment: Have you measured the time to load 100 files but do nothing? Unless you have extremely ugly code, most of the time would have been spent on file IO.

Comment: I have thousands of file to normalise in efficient way. But it takes more time.

Comment: Just a note: _if_ I were to use a switch statement like you have, I'd consider putting the 'do-nothing' cases first, to eliminate the need to evaluate against the other 26 cases first. I'd also consider putting the cases in order of the frequency with which letters are found in the average passage of text of the chosen language. See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_analysis and here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency

Comment: does the file *only* contain ASCII characters?

Comment: yes file is text file.

Comment: @enhzflep: In a switch like that, the compiler will generate code based on a table, or possibly a short chain of `if/else` - at the most three for that set. There's no benefit at all from re-organising the code, the compiler will not generate the code in the order you write it anyway.

Comment: @MatsPetersson - thanks for reminding me just how much better compilers are now than when I was in uni. :) - I can confirm that the function is compiled byte-for-byte identically with the 'do-nothing' cases presented as is or first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the OP claimed it take 12 seconds to process 100 file, I got a much faster measurement.

TL;DR;

```
Time for OPs method: 0.006472 seconds
Faster method: 0.005364 seconds
```

---

First, let's define the measurement metric: We ignore the time spent on file I/O since it cannot be avoided in the implementation level we focused.

We define the data processing function with this interface:

```
int testcase (uint8_t* des, size_t deslen, const uint8_t* src, size_t srclen);
```

Then, we measure time spent with N iterations, for simplicity we choose N=1:

```
T0 = chrono::system_clock::now();
test_base(des1, testdata_size, src, testdata_size);
T1 = chrono::system_clock::now();
```

Once we have more scientific measurement, we now have objective idea on what is faster.
However, I should point out that there are no generic algorithm that is fastest in all cases, that's why you have different algorithms.

For this particular test, we should consider the *input sample space* and design a processing such that it is optimised for such input sample statistically.

I assume the input sample is in plan English, such that most are ASCII character, and in lower cases, with few TAB, SPACE and line feeds; if this is not the case, my method will be slower.

Now, with the above assumption, I keep track of processed characters, and group together the output with a `memcpy`, this yields a slightly faster measure in this particular case.

---

The full source: compile with `clang -lstdc++ -O2 a.cpp -o a`

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;


int test_base(uint8_t* des, size_t deslen, const uint8_t* src, size_t srclen) {
    int i, j;
    if ( deslen < srclen ) return -1;
    for (i=0, j=0; i<srclen; ++i) {
        switch (src[i]) {
        case 'a':
        case 'b':
        case 'c':
        case 'd':
        case 'e':
        case 'f':
        case 'g':
        case 'h':
        case 'i':
        case 'j':
        case 'k':
        case 'l':
        case 'm':
        case 'n':
        case 'o':
        case 'p':
        case 'q':
        case 'r':
        case 's':
        case 't':
        case 'u':
        case 'v':
        case 'w':
        case 'x':
        case 'y':
        case 'z':
            des[j] = src[i] - 32;
            ++j;
            break;

        case ' ':
        case '\t':
        case '\r':
        case '\n':
            break;

        default:
            des[j] = src[i];
            ++j;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int testcase_1(uint8_t* des, size_t deslen, const uint8_t* src, size_t srclen) {
    const uint8_t* end = src + srclen;
    const uint8_t* head = src;
    size_t   len;

    if ( deslen < srclen ) return -1;
    for (; src < end; src++) {
        uint8_t value = *src;
        if ( value >= 'a' && value <='z' ) {
            size_t len = (size_t)(src - head);
            if ( len > 0 ) memcpy ( des, head, len );
            des[len] = value-32;
            des += len+1;
            head = src+1;
        } else if ( value == ' ' || value == '\t' || value == '\r' || value == '\n' ) {
            size_t len = (size_t)(src - head);
            if ( len > 0 ) memcpy ( des, head, len );
            des += len;
            head = src+1;
        } else {
            // Do Nothing
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    chrono::time_point<chrono::system_clock>T0, T1;
    uint64_t duration;

    // Create test data
    uint8_t *src, *des1, *des2;
    const size_t testdata_size = 1024*1024; // 1MB
    src = new uint8_t[testdata_size];
    des1 = new uint8_t[testdata_size];
    des2 = new uint8_t[testdata_size];
    // TODO: seed
    for ( size_t i=0; i<testdata_size; i++ ) {
        src[i] = (uint8_t)rand();
    }
    // Put things in cache and realize the memory
    memset ( des1, 0, testdata_size);
    memset ( des2, 0, testdata_size);

    T0 = chrono::system_clock::now();
    test_base(des1, testdata_size, src, testdata_size);
    T1 = chrono::system_clock::now();
    duration = chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(T1-T0).count();
    cout << "Duration: " << (duration/1.0E9) << endl;

    T0 = chrono::system_clock::now();
    testcase_1(des2, testdata_size, src, testdata_size);
    T1 = chrono::system_clock::now();
    duration = chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(T1-T0).count();
    cout << "Duration: " << (duration/1.0E9) << endl;
    if ( memcmp ( des1, des2, testdata_size ) == 0 ) {
        cout << "Meaningless compare to prevent optimize!";
    }
    delete des2;
    delete des1;
    delete src;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No need to avoid the `if (len > 0)`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751797/can-i-call-memcpy-and-memmove-with-number-of-bytes-set-to-zero - it saves an `if` inside your inner loop per processed character.

Comment: Why calculate `len`, though? Would it not simply increase by 1 on every succesful iteration, not otherwise? And it seems to me your `memcpy` is only used to 'copy' a single character. It could be useful for a scenario of alternating *blocks* of 'copy/process' characters, but in this case there is no need.