# Can it be expensive to call `memcpy` with a zero count?

Tags: c++, c, memcpy

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3751797/200783) makes it clear that it is safe to call `memcpy` passing zero as the number of bytes to copy. However, the implementation of Lua avoids doing this, claiming empty `memcpy` ["may be expensive"](https://github.com/lua/lua/commit/462375ba47de2052687b3d17ff2eef4db4cab739), or at least, is ["not that cheap"](https://github.com/lua/lua/blob/9e6807c3c9d5036e999f636f936df07b72284442/lstrlib.c#L164).

I would have thought that calling `memcpy` with a zero count would be more-or-less free - could it be expensive in certain situations?

Comment: Compared to what? It's not free, but it is cheap, but if you're going to call it gazillions of times per second it is certainly not free.

Comment: The real question is whether adding a check for a zero count to your code is more expensive that relying on the check that `memcpy` makes. The answer is *it depends*.

Comment: For any/all questions regarding performance you need to measure with your tool chain, on your platform and with your workload.  Other people's testing in their environment(s) may give you a rough indication but not an expectation to get similar results yourself.

Comment: Once upon a time a function call was significantly more expensive than an `if(n != 0)` test.  But today that tends to be less true, and `memcpy` is likely to be inlined anyway, so it's probably a wash.

Comment: @ArminMontigny Incorrect. It *can.* It *may* not be. Only measurements can tell, or an intimate acquiatance with the unnamed compiler.

Comment: Ask the guy who made those commits in lua, he probably doesn't know what he's talking about. The unnecessary check is actually slowing down the code for no good reason.

Comment: And, if the author did know that `memcpy` with zero length was slow for some reason, they were negligent not to provide information along with their statement. Such a claim ought to be supported by evidence so that future readers have reason to believe it and can adapt the code to changing circumstances.