# Is behaviour of this function defined?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

```
int *shiftRmemmove(int *arr, size_t size)
{
    if(arr && size)
    {
        memmove(arr + size - 1, arr + size - 2, (size - 1) *sizeof(*arr));
        arr[0] = 0;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Is it defined if `size == 1`? It is calculating and passing reference to the elemet of the array one ***before** the first element. it is equivalent to: `memove(arr, arr -1, 0);` *(©Jabberwocky)*

Comment: So you're basically asking if it is OK to write `memmove(arr, arr - 1, 0)`, when `arr` is pointing to the start of an array.

Comment: @Jabberwocky yes

Comment: @AndrewHenle removed

Comment: The question is different, but this is answered in the accepted answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751797/can-i-call-memcpy-and-memmove-with-number-of-bytes-set-to-zero: **Unless explicitly stated otherwise in the description of a particular function in this subclause, pointer arguments on such a call shall still have valid values**

Comment: @Barmar That's why this is a `language-lawyer` question.  :-)  FWIW, I do seem to remember recent discussion about zero-length copies.  Maybe in the context of C23 (as if that's going to make it by the end of this year...)

Comment: So the question would be whether the "Copying takes place as if ..." clause is "stating otherwise".

Comment: @AndrewHenle also passing the element before the start of the array.

Comment: If `arr` is a pointer to the first element of an array and if `size` is 1, then even attempting to form the address `arr + size - 2` is undefined behavior.

Comment: @adabsurdum it marked "language-lawyer" and I am not asking about the "opinion". Can you prove it using the standard?

Comment: @gulpr -- Not an opinion, this is what the Standard says. I included a reference in the answer I posted below.

Comment: Don't assume that because a pointer will not be dereferenced, that generating it is not a problem. `arr - 1` might be a trap representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arr` is a pointer, but, from the comments, we are intended to assume it points to element 0 of some array `A`.

Consider the expression `arr + size - 2`. `arr + size` is uncontroversial; it points to `&A[1]`, even if `A` is an array of 1 element, so that `&A[1]` is the address “just beyond” the last element of the array.

For `arr + size - 2`, effectively `&A[1] - 2`, we consider C 2018 6.5.6 8:

> If the pointer operand points to an element of an array object, and the array is large enough, the result points to an element offset from the original element such that the difference of the subscripts of the resulting and original array elements equals the integer expression. In other words, if the expression `P` points to the *i*-th element of an array object, the expressions `(P)+N` (equivalently, `N+(P)`) and `(P)-N` (where `N` has the value *n*) point to, respectively, the *i* + *n*-th and *i* − *n*-th elements of the array object, **provided they exist** [emphasis added]…

This passage does not define the result of `&A[1] - 2` because the element of array `A` with index −1 does not exist. This alone suffices to render the behavior not defined, because nothing else in the standard defines it, and C 2018 4 2 tells us “Undefined behavior is otherwise indicated in this document… by the omission of any explicit definition of behavior.” However, 6.5.6 8 continues:

> … If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior is undefined…

Here the pointer operand (`&A[1]`) and the result (`&(A[-1]`) do not point to elements of the same array object or one past it, so the behavior is undefined.

Evaluation of `arr + size - 2` occurs before `memmove` is called, so whether `memmove` uses its corresponding parameter is irrelevant; the behavior is already undefined.

Answer (score 6):

If `arr` is a pointer to the first element of an array and if `size` is 1, then even attempting to form the address `arr + size - 2` is undefined behavior. This is spelled out in the C Standard (C23 Draft Standard 6.5.6 9):

> When an expression that has integer type is added to or subtracted from a pointer,.... If the pointer operand and the result do not point to elements of the same array object or one past the last element of the array object, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: What about `char a[42]; shiftRmemmove(a+1, 0);`?

Comment: Yep  - as it can overflow.

Comment: It is partial answer UV-ted

Comment: @AllanWind "if both the pointer
operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last
element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; "

Comment: @gulpr -- _"as it can overflow."_ The Standard does say something about this, as you referenced, but this is not why it is undefined behavior. It is undefined behavior because the Standard says explicitly that it is in the passage that I quoted. Another way to think about this is that C doesn't allow you to form a pointer to one object using a pointer to another object and pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the [C standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2310.pdf) ch. 7.24.1 sub-clause 2 (applies for all functions in `<string.h>` - emphasis mine):

> Where an argument declared as size_t n specifies the length of the array for a function, n can have
> the value zero on a call to that function. Unless explicitly stated otherwise in the description of a
> particular function in this subclause, **pointer arguments on such a call shall still have valid values**, as
> described in 7.1.4. On such a call, a function that locates a character finds no occurrence, a function
> that compares two character sequences returns zero, and a function that copies characters copies zero characters.

so you are forming a call:

```
memove(arr, arr -1, 0);
```

where the second (pointer) argument has no valid value. The standard explicitly forbids you from forming such pointers, since chapter 7.1.4 (pointed by first quote) mentions that:

> **If an argument to a function has an invalid value** (such as a value outside the domain of the
> function, or a pointer outside the address space of the program, or a null pointer, or a pointer
> to non-modifiable storage when the corresponding parameter is not const-qualified) or a type
> (after default argument promotion) not expected by a function with a variable number of
> arguments, **the behavior is undefined**.

Verdict: the standard explicitly forbids this. The behavior is undefined.